# Specifying which fields to return in group() query

Tags: mongodb, field

How can I specify which fields to return in a `group()` query? `find()` has `fields` parameter; `group()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Write a javascript function that removes the fields you don't want and pass it to the `finalize` parameter of `group`

Comment: Isn't it going to slow down the query?